# Split on / only if surrounded by text

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to split  `1/2 chicken/‏ greens/egg/tomato/blue cheese/bacon` for `/` only if the `/` is surrounded by `[a-z ]` and not by numbers

I have tried:

- `#[^0-9]\/[^0-9]#i`
- `#[a-z ]\/[a-z ]#i`
- `#(?:[a-z ])\/(?:[a-z ])#i`

But it capture also the text

(If it matters, I am using `preg_split` in PHP where the modifier `g` is always implicitly used)

Comment: Why don't you just match the desired portions of the string?

Comment: because the string in my case comes from a random source and it not always formatted this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<!\d)\/(?!\d)
```

You can split by this.Use `lookarounds`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/101

EDIT:

```
(?<=\D)\/|\/(?=\D)
```

Use this it `/` having an integer on one side should be split.

Comment: Think positive: `(?<=\D)\/(?=\D)` :)

Comment: @stribizhev yups either way :P

Comment: almost, I modified the string to show other cases.  this will skip `text/number/text` case

Comment: Awesome.  Yes, `(?<=\D)\/|\/(?=\D)` works.  didn't think about seeing the problem from "there has to be a char before or after".  Thank you